# How do I have matplotlib plot different edgecolors for different classes with facecolors='none'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot like this

[image]

which means `facecolors='none'`

This code

```
X, y = make_circles(100, factor=.1, noise=.1)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50, cmap='autumn', facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
```

gives

[image]

which use red for both classes.

It's because when I tried to use `edgecolors=y`

```
X, y = make_circles(100, factor=.1, noise=.1)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50, cmap='autumn', facecolors='none', edgecolors=y)
```

I got this error

```
    261     # tuple color.
    262     if not np.iterable(c):
--> 263         raise ValueError(f"Invalid RGBA argument: {orig_c!r}")
    264     if len(c) not in [3, 4]:
    265         raise ValueError("RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4")
```

How do I use edgecolors correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edgecolors is not like c

The `cmap` parameter will only be applied to `c`. But `c` will overwrite `facecolors="none"` so we don't want to use it.

Unlike the parameter `c`, the parameter `edgecolors` must receive values that are directly interpretable as colors, meaning rgb or rgba values, color_strings... or any format specified in this [matplotlib colors page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html).

You can pass `y` to a cmap :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cmap = plt.get_cmap("winter")
colors = cmap(y * 255) # or cmap(y.astype(float))
print(colors)
# > array([[1., 1., 0., 1.], # RGBA values
#          [1., 1., 0., 1.],
#          [1., 1., 0., 1.],
#          [1., 0., 0., 1.],
#                ...       ])
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50, facecolors="none", edgecolors=colors)
```

Notice that you have to pass integers between 0 and 255 or floats between 0. and 1., to spread the colors along the cmap.

[image: Plot with cmap]

You can also infer colors from a dictionary you designed yourself :

```
color_dict = {0: "r", 1: "b"}
colors=tuple(map(color_dict.get, y))
print(colors)
# > ('b', 'b', 'b', 'r', ...)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50, facecolors="none", edgecolors=colors)
```

[image: Plot with dict]

## Markers are not like colors

You can't specify different markers in a single `scatter` call, because it only accepts a single representation of a `MarkerStyle` (as an instance of the class or as a string).

That means that you have to call `scatter` as many times as the count of different markers you want.

Furthermore, at the moment, you can't make use of `edgecolor` with the `+ markerstyle`.

The easiest way would be to mask your data by color :

```
red_mask = y==0
print(red_mask)
# > [False, False, False, True ...]
plt.scatter(X[red_mask, 0], X[red_mask, 1], s=50, facecolors="none", edgecolors="r")
plt.scatter(X[~red_mask, 0], X[~red_mask, 1], s=50, marker="+", c="b")
```

[image: Plot with markerstyle]

Another solution would be to plot each point, but it's less elegant IMO :

```
for X_x, X_y, clas in zip(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y) :
    if clas == 1:
        plt.scatter(X_x, X_y, c="b", marker="+")
    else:
        plt.scatter(X_x, X_y, facecolors="none", edgecolor="r", marker="o", )
# Same resulting plot
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  `c` will overwrite `facecolors="none"` so we don't want to use it. Does "it" refer to `c` parameter?

Comment: @yaojp Yes, exactly. Also if you set the `cmap` parameter anyways, it won't have any visible effect since we don't use `c`.