# How do I get a right radial basis function that projects non-linearly separable data to linearly separable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm trying to make a plot like this

[image]

With [@Whole Brain's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67867462/12222879), I've got this

[image]

with this code

```
X, y = make_circles(100, random_state=96867, factor=.1, noise=.1)
red_mask = y==0
plt.scatter(X[red_mask, 0], X[red_mask, 1], s=50, facecolors="none", edgecolors="r")
plt.scatter(X[~red_mask, 0], X[~red_mask, 1], s=50, marker="+", c="b")
```

However, when I tried to project the data to 3d

```
r = np.exp(-(X ** 2).sum(1))

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(X[red_mask, 0], X[red_mask, 1], facecolors="none", edgecolors="r")
ax.scatter3D(X[~red_mask, 0], X[~red_mask, 1], marker="+", c="b")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('r')
plt.show()
```

I got this

[image]

which seems to mean that the radial basis function `r = np.exp(-(X ** 2).sum(1))` doesn't work at all.

How do I get a right radial basis function that projects non-linearly separable data to linearly separable?

Comment: Are you asking how to make some data (that conforms to the first 3-d plot)? Or are you satisfied with your data and want to know how to change/rotate your plot?  Your [mre] doesn't include `make_circles` - we don't know what that is - we need to be able to reproduce your data and problem.

Comment: Probably ``sklearn.datasets.make_circles``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that the `z` coordinates are never specified, and are set to 0 by default, thus giving a planar plot in 3d-space.

Changing the plotting instructions to the snippet below, which adds this third coordinate, produces a true 3d plot:

```py
ax.scatter3D(X[red_mask, 0], X[red_mask, 1], r[red_mask], facecolors="none", edgecolors="r")
ax.scatter3D(X[~red_mask, 0], X[~red_mask, 1], r[~red_mask], marker="+", c="b")
```

[image]

To center the blue dots around 0, you'll want to change your kernel to `r = np.exp((X ** 2).sum(1))`, as the negative exponential makes the points furthest from the center have lower r values. The final result is presented below, and makes the data linearly separable (`y` was also changed to `abs(y)` to better match the example image).

[image]